# Saleseforce code covrage is low (53%) and i dont know why

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com

I'v created a class for salesforce in sandbox, and it works well, but when i'm tring to deploy it to production, i get a low code covarage. 
I tried everything i know but cat find a solution, 
Heres the code, Any help?

```
public Class CandidateFileUploads_Ver1{

public String parentId ;
public String idxVal {get;set;}
public Map<String, Attachment> attachments {get;set;}
public Map<String, Attachment> attachmentsDup {get;set;}

public Boolean validateUser {get;set;}
public String multipulDocs {get;set;}
public String userMessage {get;set;}

private static final Map<String, String> descriptionNameMap = new Map<String, String>{
'Upload a scan of the Passport'=>'Passport',
'Upload a Resume (CV)'=>'Resume (CV)'};

private static final Map<String, String> descriptionCheckFieldMap = new Map<String, String>{
'Upload a scan of the Passport'=>'Passport_Attached__c',
'Upload a Resume (CV)'=>'CV_Attached__c'};


public CandidateFileUploads_Ver1(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

    idxVal = '';
    validateUser = true;
    multipulDocs = System.Label.multiple_docs;
    userMessage = '';

    checkUserValid();
    attachments = new Map<String, Attachment>();       
    attachmentsDup = new Map<String, Attachment>();  

    parentId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id');
    //parentId = '0034E00000FVJzA';
    List<Attachment> existingAttachments = fetchAllAttachments(parentId);//get all attachements for thew user

    for(String key :descriptionNameMap.keySet()){
        String kokp = descriptionCheckFieldMap.get(key);
        attachments.put(key.toLowerCase(), new Attachment(parentId=parentId, Description=key, body=null,Name = kokp )) ;
    }    

    for(Attachment attach :existingAttachments){
        attach.body = null;
        attachments.put(attach.Description.toLowerCase(), attach);             
    }
}

 public void checkUserValid(){
    String hours = System.Label.hours;
    String whitelist = System.Label.whitelist;
    ID pId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id');
    Boolean validateUser = true;
    String userMessage;

    Contact parenter = new Contact(Id=pId);
     // Validate Proccess status: get proccess string status
            String getStatus = parenter.Process_Status__c;
            String[] whitelistArr = whitelist.split(',');// split proccess string

             Boolean checkWhiteList = false;
             for(String val : whitelistArr){
                 if(val == getStatus) {
                     checkWhiteList = true;
                 }
             }

             if(validateUser != checkWhiteList){
                 validateUser = false;
                 userMessage = System.Label.error_not_premitted;
                 return;
             }

    //Validate Dates
            //Datetime  getLinktimestamp = (Datetime) contactSObject.get('linktimestamp__c');
            Datetime  getLinktimestamp = parenter.linktimestamp__c;
            Datetime  getValidTime = getLinktimestamp.addHours(Integer.valueof(hours.trim())); //add 48 hours
            Datetime timeNow = System.now();

             if(getValidTime < timeNow){//if if more then 48 hours
                 validateUser = false;
                 userMessage = System.Label.error_expired;
                 return;
             }
 }


 public Datetime  getLinktimestamp(){
    ID pId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id');
    Datetime  accts = [SELECT linktimestamp__c FROM Contact WHERE Id=:pId].linktimestamp__c;
    return accts;
}


public List<Contact> contactObj(){
    ID pId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id');

    sObject mySObject =[SELECT linktimestamp__c,Process_Status__c FROM Contact WHERE Id=:pId];
    //Datetime llli = s.linktimestamp__c;
    String strObjectName = String.valueOf( mySObject.get('linktimestamp__c') );

    List<Contact> obj = [SELECT linktimestamp__c,Process_Status__c FROM Contact WHERE Id=:pId];
    return obj;
}

public void uploadAttachment(){     
    List<Attachment> uploads = new List<Attachment>() ;
    List<Attachment> deletes = new List<Attachment>() ;

    try{
        for(integer i = 0 ; i < attachments.values().size() ; i++){

            Attachment attach = attachments.values()[i] ;
            if(attach.parentId == NULL){
                        attach.parentId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id');
            }
            //this is a file that was uploaded now
            if(attach.body != NULL){
                //remove current attachement before uploading a new one
                if(attach.Id != NULL){
                    deletes.add(attachments.values().remove(i));
                }

                attach.Name = renameFile(attach.Name, attach.Description);
                uploads.add(attach) ;
            }
        }

        if(!deletes.isEmpty()){
            delete deletes ;
        }

        if(!uploads.isEmpty()){        
            for(Attachment atchmnt :uploads){
                atchmnt.Id = null;   
            }

            insert uploads;

            Contact parent = new Contact(Id=parentId);

            for(Attachment attach :getUpdatedAttachments(uploads).values()){
                attach.body = null;
                attachments.put(attach.Description.toLowerCase(), attach);

                parent.put(descriptionCheckFieldMap.get(attach.Description), true);                    
            }

            update parent;

            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.info,'Attachment upload Successfully');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }

    }        
    catch(exception e){
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'An Error occured when uploading attachment');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
    }
}

public void removeRow(){
    Attachment a = attachments.get(idxVal.toLowerCase());

    Contact parent = new Contact(Id=parentId);
    parent.put(descriptionCheckFieldMap.get(a.Description), false); 

    delete a;
    update parent;

    system.debug('attachments before: ' + attachments);
    attachments.put(a.Description.toLowerCase(), new Attachment(parentId = parentId, description = a.description, body=null));
    system.debug('attachments after: ' + attachments);
}    

private static String renameFile(String fileName, String description){
    String newName = descriptionNameMap.get(description);
    if(String.isNotBlank(fileName) && fileName.contains('.')){
        newName += fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'), fileName.length());
    }

    return newName;
} 

private static Map<String,Attachment> getUpdatedAttachments(List<Attachment> attachList){

    Map<String,Attachment> attMap = new Map<String,Attachment>();

    for(Attachment att : [SELECT Id,Name,Description
                                      FROM Attachment
                                      WHERE Id = :attachList]){
        attMap.put(att.Description.toLowerCase(), att) ;       
    }

    return attMap;
}

public List<Attachment> fetchAllAttachments(String parentId){

    return [SELECT Id,Name,Description,parentId
            FROM Attachment 
            WHERE ParentId =: parentId 
            AND Description IN :descriptionNameMap.keySet()];
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys.
But the main issue was that i had to write a test class (Sorry but i did not knew that). and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Developer Console to see wich part of your code is covered and wich is not and then adapt your tests.
When editing code in the developer console, there is a 'Code coverage' option at the top left of the page.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "I tried everything i know but cat find a solution"? It's Salesforce requirement - Apex code should be covered by tests at least on 75%. The deployment fails if the average coverage  doesn’t meet the 75% threshold.

The only solution here is to write tests for your code.

Comment: how can i write test for constructor and for methods with arguments?

Comment: What prevents you to call in test methods your constructors or methods with arguments? For instance, here is discussion of testing controller constructor - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zbRIAQ

Comment: Also, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm might be of help.